# How do I set label for an already plotted line in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend, axis-labels

In my code I've already executed

```
ax.plot(x, y, 'b.-', ...)
```

and need to be able to set the label for the corresponding line after the fact, to have the same effect as if I'd

```
ax.plot(x, y, 'b.-', label='lbl', ...)
```

Is there a way to do this in Matplotlib?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you grab the `line2D` object when you create it, you can set the label using `line.set_label()`:

```
line, = ax.plot(x, y, 'b.-', ...)
line.set_label('line 1')
```

If you don't, you can find the `line2D` from the `Axes`:

```
ax.plot(x, y, 'b.-', ...)
ax.lines[-1].set_label('line 1')
```

Note, `ax.lines[-1]` will access the last line created, so if you make more than one line, you would need to be careful which line you set the label on using this method.

---

A minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
l,=ax.plot(range(5))
l.set_label('line 1')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was using `ax.set_label` to no effect. Can you explain why `ax.set_label` does not work here?

Comment: `ax.set_label` would set the label of the `Axes` instance, not the line. Since you can have multiple lines on an `Axes`, its not clear what the Axes label would be used for

Comment: After adjusting the label in a real time updated plot that is redrawn by `fig.canvas.draw()`, I needed to run `ax.legend()` to redraw the legend itself.

Comment: Are there any occasions when `l = ax.plot(...)` (i.e. *without a comma*) would return a list containing more than one `Line2D` object?

Comment: @pfabri of course, if you plot more than one line in your `ax.plot` command