# suppress label in xarray.DataArray.plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray

I'm using `xarray.DataArray.plot` to plot my values, such as:

```
In [26]: cla()

In [27]: da = xarray.DataArray(arange(6*5).reshape(6,5), dims=("a", "b"), coords={"a": range(6), "b": range(5), "c": ("a", range(6))})

In [28]: da["c"].plot(label="a")
Out[28]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fef942e8b38>]

In [29]: da["c"].plot(label=None)
Out[29]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fef94279dd8>]

In [30]: legend()
Out[30]: <matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x7fef942cba20>
```

My desired effect is that the `da["c"].plot(label=None)` does not result in any labelled line.  However, `xarray` appears to give it a label `"c"` in the resulting plot, whereby it appears in the legend.  How can I suppress this?

[image: Resulting plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xarray's plotting module seems to skip the legend entry if you pass an empty string:

```
da["c"].plot(label="a")
da["c"].plot(label='')
legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to set the label after the line has been plotted, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36624564/974555):

```
In [46]: L = da["c"].plot(label=None)    

In [47]: L[0].set_label(None)
```